# Querying sub queries does not appear to work

Tags: sql

This question is on the back of a recent question about sub queries in SQL. Thanks to the help from folk on SO I received a code block that I believe should work but does not run:

```
SELECT usersAndDlCount.NIM_USER_ID, usersAndDlCount.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID
FROM (SELECT VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID, COUNT(VwNIMEventFct.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID)
    FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
    WHERE NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884
    GROUP BY NIM_USER_ID) usersAndDlCount
WHERE NIM_USER_ID >100
```

This is perhaps not the best example since I could just add the last WHERE clause within the sub query but at this point I just want to see it working.

Can anyone spot what is wrong here?

Comment: What results do you expect?  The subquery has no field called `NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your `COUNT(VwNIMEventFct.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID)` a name, otherwise SQL will create some name for you. Try this:

```
SELECT usersAndDlCount.NIM_USER_ID, usersAndDlCount.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID
FROM (SELECT NIM_USER_ID, COUNT(NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID) AS NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID
    FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
    WHERE NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884
    GROUP BY NIM_USER_ID) usersAndDlCount
WHERE NIM_USER_ID >100
```

Comment: Ah thanks, yes when I tried yesterday I had to wait for the time limit to end

Answer (score 1):

Your query is referring to a field that doesn't exist in the subquery, `NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID`.  If you just want the users, you don't need the subquery, a `having` or `where` clause will do:

```
  SELECT ef.NIM_USER_ID, COUNT(ef.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID) as cnt
  FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct ef
  WHERE ef.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884 AND NIM_USER_ID > 100
  GROUP BY ef.NIM_USER_ID;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP specifically wanted the sub-query because he wanted to know how it works.

Comment: AND keyword is missing in the query above. I could not edit (because the edit was < 6 characters).